# SSIS Access Database - Need to empty table on my destination Access Database table before inserting new records

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssis, oledb, etl

**Task:**

Transfer data from SQL Server into Access Database

**Issue:**

How to empty my Access destination table before I run the data flow?

I tried to use an Execute SQL Task to run a TRUNCATE command similar to SQL Server, but it seems not working with Access Database?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In Access VBA: `CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM tablename"`. No idea how would be done from SSIS. How do you connect to tables? Why would records need to be deleted? Why not Access just connect to SQLServer tables?

Comment: The reason using SSIS is because it need to pass away to other team to run the package, but they might not have access grant in Access database or SQL Server

Comment: Doesn't user need to be authorized to use db in order to programmatically change db data?

Comment: Good point. So by using SSIS I can save my password inside the package, basically, they will run the package but use my identity/password. It's the outbound team and they scheduled for automation running the package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Execute SQL Task to query a Microsoft Access Database, but you cannot use a Truncate command since it is not supported, you have to use a `DELETE FROM ...` command.

The following screenshots show an example of the OLE DB Connection manager, and the Execute SQL Task configuration:

[image]

[image]